# How to transfer photos from camera to PC over Wi-Fi (Canon S110) Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, canon, camera, photo-management

The Canon S110 comes with an optical disk containing a software bundle for Windows (and of course nothing for Linux), including an utility for connecting to the computer through WiFi.

Also I think worth noting is that in Windows the transfer process requires Media Streaming and Network Discovery to be turned on. I think this would be key points for enabling photo transfer on Ubuntu also, but I cannot find [the equivalent of] these options anywhere.

[This link](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/cameras/Digital_Compact/Powershot_S_series/PowerShot_S110.aspx?faqtcmuri=tcm:13-1033061&page=1&type=faq) explains the process for Windows.

So the question is how can I transfer my photos from the camera to my Ubuntu PC over wireless?

I love the wireless option on the Canon S110 and have been using it intensely before switching over to Linux, I don't like to mess with cables. Anyway, I already lost the original cable. Also my PC has no card reader.

I am using both Xubuntu and Mint 16 XFCE.

Comment: get a cable.they are cheap.

Comment: Thank you for the piece of advice but I'd prefer to use this fabulous, magic, no strings attached method called Wi-Fi transfer;)

Comment: @brett: thanks for the acceptance!  Favour returned!  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Airnef](http://www.testcams.com/airnef) is an open source tool that can be used to transfer files from Canon, Nikon and Sony cameras (at the time of this writing).

> Airnef is two applications - a GUI front-end and a command-line app. The GUI front-end allows you to visually select the criteria of which images to download and then launches the command-line app to perform the transfer. You can optionally use the command-line version directly to script your transfers.

[Here is the download link to the 1.1 binaries](http://www.testcams.com/airnef/Version_1.1/airnef_v1.1_Linux_Binary.tar.gz) but people interested in python [should download the source](http://www.testcams.com/airnef/Version_1.1/airnef_v1.1_Source.zip).

Comment: it's perfect but unfortunately not supporting canon 1300D. after connecting just closes with an error

Comment: @azerafati the EOS 1300D is from 2016 and the binaries haven't been updated since 2015, so read the [Airnef FAQ](http://www.testcams.com/airnef/) first. If that doesn't help, contact the developers [here](http://testcams.com/blog/forums/forum/airnef-wireless-download-from-your-nikon-camera/).

Comment: tanx, though their forum sucks. Wish they had discovered SE